# Aws Lambda Called twice but without errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This lambda is being invoked from another lambda. The lambda that is calling this one invokes with type **EVENT** which means it calls this lambda asynchronously. The timeout for this lambda is 4 minutes. I have read that it is normal that a lambda is called twice if something goes wrong and then it retries with the same requestId. However, there is no log on cloud watch regarding an error.

[image: Lambda called twice]

As you can see there are two START one at 18:24:44 and then 18:30:08. However, between those two requests nothing happened on the lambda (error etc). But, the second time the lambda is called, it executes normally. Is this a normal behaviour on lambdas?

**EDIT**

Here we have the 2 log groups that AWS created between the 2 invocation

[image]

Here is the first invocation that has nothing more than the log of Start and the RequestId

[image]

And here is the second attempt of execution with the same RequestId 6 minutes later.

[image]

What it does not make sense to me is that there are no logs explaining why that happened.

Comment: FYI, asynchronous events are queued before being used to invoke the Lambda function. If AWS Lambda is unable to fully process the event, it will automatically retry the invocation twice, with delays between retries.

Comment: @jarmod I did not know about the queue when an asynchronous is called. This explains why it retries if something goes wrong. However, what I would like to know is why there are no logs regarding what went wrong? It just retried after a few minutes without explicit reason. It means that it is probably something related to AWS infrastructure?

Comment: If the Lambda function was triggered (and your Lambda function has an appropriate IAM role) then you will see at least START and END logs. If the Lambda service retried the invocation then it's likely because the initial invocation failed or timed out. Note that you have to be a little careful with CloudWatch Logs because in a distributed system like this, you may have to review multiple log streams to see the full picture. Plus they are slightly delayed behind the Lambda execution so you may have to wait a short time (and refresh the logs).

Comment: @jarmod I understand your point but still it does not make sense why it was called twice because I have called this flow multiple times but only this time the lambda was called twice without errors on the cloud watch logs. I know they are log streams and it may be delayed but until now (15 hours later) there is only 1 log of Start the lambda and nothing anymore until it is called again. Also, I do not think it is time out because the avg duration is 10 seconds and the time out is 4 minutes and also because there are no logs of time out.

Comment: Same here, and I agree it does not make any sense, my process goes smoothly and everything works fine, but the lambda gets executed two times for no absolute reason.